# CCMotionStreak setColor cannot work in cocos2d 3.1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

It keeps showing the black color.

Following is my demo code:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self beginMotionStreak];
}

- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self addMotionStreak:[touch locationInWorld]];
}

- (void)touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self endMotionStreak];
}

- (void)beginMotionStreak
{
    CCMotionStreak *streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:10 minSeg:1.0 width:5.0 color:[CCColor greenColor] texture:nil];
    [self addChild:streak z:1 name:@"streak"];
}

- (void)addMotionStreak:(CGPoint)touchLoc
{
    CCMotionStreak *streak = (CCMotionStreak *)[self getChildByName:@"streak" recursively:YES];
    [streak setColor:[CCColor redColor]];
    [streak setPosition:touchLoc];
}

- (void)endMotionStreak
{
    [self removeChildByName:@"streak" cleanup:YES];
}
```

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need to specify a texture** used as a shape for motion streak. Just create small round or rectangle **white** image and specify it as a texture when creating `CCMotionStreak`:

```
- (void)beginMotionStreak
{
    CCMotionStreak *streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:10 minSeg:1.0 width:5.0 color:[CCColor greenColor] textureFilename:@"motion_streak.png"];
    [self addChild:streak z:1 name:@"streak"];
}
```

Note that last parameter name will be `textureFilename` not `texture`, otherwise you need to load texture yourself first and pass the instance instead of the file name.

**Why the texture should be white?** Because the color you set later is multiplied with the color of the texture.

If you're unsure about the shape of the image just try creating different ones in any graphics editor. I've used Gimp, but that's an overkill for such a simple task.